# POST to localhost failed with 404 - "Social" by Mailchimp

Tags: php, wordpress, localhost, mailchimp

I'm running wordpress with XAMPP using the "Social" plugin. When trying to log into facebook/twitter from within the admin menu I get

```
POST to http://127.0.0.1/wordpress/index.php?social_controller=auth&social_action=authorized&salt=a3abbd88f12bd9f7d08e1b6c6c0e2d44&is_admin=true&user_id=1 failed with 404
```

I've been searching the web for hours trying to find a solution to this, any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Please test this on live server.
Social plugin functionality is not working properly on localhost or local system, you have to test on live server to be confirmed working

Answer (score 0):

From [reading between the lines on MailChimp's fora](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-test-this-in-localhost); the company does not, and apparently never will, allow API calls or endpoint submissions from localhost.